# How does a phone know when it is being charged?

Tags: android

Which command or software is used to tell that you are charging your phone battery?

Comment: No software tells your phone to charge your battery .It's **hardware**. Physical. Plug the cable and the current flows, charging your battery.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know or get Notified when charger is connected or removed, Then you can use Intent broadcast receiver Intent.Action.BatteryChanged